# How to download a youtube video through pytube python module

Tags: python, python-3.7, pytube, kali-linux

Here is the code:

```
>>> from pytube import YouTube
>>> v=YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wl2OyaZVU3U')
>>> v.title
'Maroon 5 - Memories (Lyrics)'
>>> v.streams
<pytube.query.StreamQuery object at 0x7f76859e3a20>
>>> v.download()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    v.download()
AttributeError: 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'download'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: pytube is no longer maintained, consider using pytube3 instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an exemple on the library [documentation](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#downloading-a-video) where it uses the streams member of the object in order to download.

In your code that would be :

```
>>> v.streams.first().download()
```

See also the [API doc](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#youtube-object).